Problem with \input with pdflatex
I'm having a problem when using the \input command with PdfLatex to compile. I have two files, the first one and the other to include with \input.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{intro}

\input{first section.tex}
\end{document}

and this is the second
\lipsum[1-10]

When I compile with quick compilation it works, but if I pass to PdfLatex it gives me this error. Do you know why? I'm using TexMaker, with Overleaf I don't have this problem.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please copy and paste "this error".  What do you mean by "pass to pdflatex" as opposed to "quick compilation"?  You can also try dropping the .tex extension from the \input command.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what is the exact  error you get, show the full log from that example

first section.tex should work unless you have a very old latex release (if you had shown the log that would show the release) but I would never use spaces in file names

how do you call pdflatex do you change directory to the directory with the documents or do you pass the full path to the file?  (if you had shown the log this would be clear)

If you have a directory (folder) tdir  with file.tex having your first file and first section.tex having the second then if you cd to tdir and run pdflatex file then the terminal output will look like
$ pdflatex file
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./file.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(./file.aux) (./first section.tex)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]
[3] (./file.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on file.pdf (3 pages, 31649 bytes).
Transcript written on file.log.

If however you are in a different directory then it will fail. Moving to the parent directory and using pdflatex tdir/file.tex produces terminal output:
$ cd ..

$ pdflatex tdir/file.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tdir/file.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(./file.aux)

! LaTeX Error: File `first section.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 

The local path first section.tex is relative to the working directory of the TeX process running the job, it is not relative to the tex file containing the \input command.
You could change to \input{tdir/first section.tex} but better is to process the document as shown first, ensuring the pdflatex process is executing in the same directory as your main file.
